# How do I display local storage items in a list?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am new to react and I am consistently stuck when it comes to this (dissapoinitng ik).
I am working on a checkout page and I would like to display a summary of the items the user purchased from their cart. Said items are saved in the localStorage. When I console.log this information, it shows up. But I am stuck on how I can display these results in a list. I'll provide my code but it is choppy so no judgement pls

**Review.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography, List, ListItem, ListItemText } from "@material-ui/core";
import CartItems from "../Cart/CartItems";
import Product from "../Products/Product/Product";
import CartLayout from "../Cart/CartLayout";

const Review = ({ items }) => {

  console.log(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
  return (

    <div>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        {" "}
        Order Summary
      </Typography>
        {items.map((item) => (
            <ListItem style={{ padding: '10px 0' }} key={item.VinylID}>
                item={item}
            </ListItem>
          ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Review;
```

**PaymentForm.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography, Button, Divider } from "@material-ui/core";
// import { Element  } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js '
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import Review from "./Review";

class PaymentForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let shoppingCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
    this.state = {
       items: [] 
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Review items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PaymentForm;
```

I will answer any questions about my code that I can since I know it may come off a bit vague

thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to see the format of the content of `shoppingCart`, but for sure you'd want to use it in your items list, no?

```
class PaymentForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const shoppingCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
    return (
      <div>
        <Review items={shoppingCart} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The better question might be: how does your shopping cart change, and does this list need to re-render reactively. But this here seems like a good first step.